# Displaying single QML item in several views

Tags: c++, qt, qml

In my Qt application, I have two separate views, that are supposed to display single QML item. It means, any changes like adding child items are to be displayed in both views. Yet, those views have to be rendered separately.

Similar example is like displaying one image in two views with different position, zoom level and resolution

Comment: That will need two item instances. I'd keep the state that defines how the item is displayed in C++ and bind the two instances to it.

Comment: Flyweight. One instance of your image or image wrapper or image handler or image whatever and two instances of your graphics item. Change the leaf once, change the world wherever it is used.